# Sprites se sobreponen Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity2d

Hola estoy desarrollando un simulador en unity el problema que tengo es con los Sprites que vendrían siendo herramientas en el juego/simulador, en este caso debo usar unos 8 sprites que simulan ser objetos los cuales tengo que tomarlos y arrastrarlos a otro objeto todo esto de forma "touch" para SmartPhones, lo que ocurre es que cuando tomo un sprite y paso sobre otro sprite estos se absorben y luego no los puedo separar volviéndose un bug. a continuación les muestro el codigo que utilizo para el movimiento ojala puedan ayudar para saber que agregar para solucionar esto.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class movimiento : MonoBehaviour {


    public float speed = 0.1F; 
    public bool calor = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            print(Input.touchCount);

        //Gets the world position of the mouse on the screen        
        Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint( Input.mousePosition );

        //Checks whether the mouse is over the sprite
        bool overSprite = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.Contains( mousePosition );

        //If it's over the sprite
        if (overSprite)
        {
            //If we've pressed down on the mouse (or touched on the iphone)
            if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
            {
                //Set the position to the mouse position
                this.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x,
                    Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y,
                    0.0f);
            }
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "cabeza")
            calor = true;
            Debug.Log ("ouch");
            Debug.Log (calor);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el componente Sprite, tienes un campo llamado "Sorting Order" y debajo "Order in Layer". Estos dos campos te permiten controlar qué sprite deber verse por delante del otro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

No estoy muy seguro de a qué te refierres con "se absorven", una captura de pantalla o un video del bug estería bien, pero por lo que entiendo pueden ser dos cosas.

La primera es que los dos sprites se sobreponen y comienza a verse uno encima del otro de manera aleatoria, eso se soluciona con el orden de las capas en 2D para Unity [Unity Sorting layers](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/sorting-layers).

Si no es el de arriba, lo que entiendo, de nuevo una captura o video del bug estaría bien, es que tocas un sprite y si al moverlo pasas sobre otro sprite entonces mueves ambos sprites y como se quedaron juntos entonces ya no puedes volver a seleccionar uno solo.

De ser este el problema la solución es simple. Cuando tocas un sprite seteas una bandera a true, esta bandera sabe si ya tocamos, o no, un objeto y si ya tocaste un objeto entonces el raycast ya no tiene efecto sobre los demás o en su defecto ya no se dispara. Algo así

```
if(!bTengoSprite)
{
  SeleccionObjetoConRaycast();
}
```

Recuerda que al quitar el touch de la pantalla debes setear la bandera a false para que te deje volver a cachar otro objeto.

Espero sea de ayuda.
Saludos.